# R: Unexpected error when stacking rasters

Tags: r, stack, raster

I'm trying to stack 21 raster files using this code:

```
setwd("D:/LANDSAT8/2016/LC8221077/all/")

img = stack(list.files(pattern=".TIF$"))

names(img) <- c(paste0("B", 1:21, coll = ""))
```

But when I run it, it show's this error message:

> `Error in rep.int(names(x), lengths(x)) : invalid 'times' value`

How can I solve it?

Comment: can you please edit the console output of `img` into your question?

Comment: The `names...` line should work fine if you have the correct number of layers in the stack. 1st check how many layers.  Or if error is in the `img=stack...` line? If so, what does `list.files(pattern=".TIF$")` by itself produce?

Comment: Also, have a thourough read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), especially the section on rasters.  You need to make a reproducible example before posting here. As it stands no-one but you can run your code to test it.  There is a good chance that during the creation of a minimal reproducible example you will find out for yourself what the issue is.

Comment: wild guess: have you loaded the raster library: `library(raster)` .
I got this error message once when I forgot to load it in my script.

Comment: @loki the initial post didn't have the `library(raster)` call. Did you add it in your edit?

Comment: @maRtin, that is correct. I did not think of the possibility that it was missing.

Answer (score 0):

as @maRtin explained in his comment: you probably forgot to load

```
library(raster)
```

Thus, you use `utils::stack.default()` which is not defined for `Raster*Objects` as also mentioned [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/StackRaster-problem-td4696033.html).